# ERROR while calling backed api : net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED from client container in docker

Tags: angular, .net-core, docker-compose

I am trying a simple client server communication with angular and .net core.

ERROR is  while calling backed api  :

http://backend:5000/api/WeatherForecast **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

---

my docker compose yml file is :

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend_image  
    build: ./api/
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"

  client:
    container_name: client
    image: client_image
    build: ./client/
    ports:
      - "4201:80"
    depends_on: 
      - backend
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "81:80"
```

---

nginx.conf file is :

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;    
    
    location /api/ {
     proxy_pass         http://backend:5000; 
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://client:80;
    }
  }
}
```

---

I am calling backed api from angular like :

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.http.get<string[]>('http://backend:5000/api/WeatherForecast').subscribe(values => {             // <========= getting error here 
    console.log(values)

  });
  }
```

}

I am trying this for last 2 days but failed to resolved

Comment: Change from http:backend:5000 to Http://localhost:5000